# Facebook oauth dialog POST method for return uri

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-graph-api

## Short version

Is there a way to have facebook POST back to your return url from their oauth dialog after logging in?

## With background story

I am developing a Rails application in which a user can buy products. In order to buy a product, he has to request it by creating a Request. That Request stores the product's id, the product owner's id as well as the requester's id, just to associate the three with each other.

All this happens through a form that is sent, of course, through a post request.

Here comes the tricky part: The user has to be logged in to place a request. They can log in through facebook. In my application controller, I currently have the following method to check if a user is logged in:

```
def user_signed_in?
  unless current_user # from other method
    flash[:error] = "Please log in first."
    redirect_to root_path and return false
  end

  true
end
helper_method :user_signed_in?
```

I want to change `root_path` to the facebook auth dialog url. At the moment, I have the following:

```
def user_signed_in?
  unless current_user
    raise "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth/?client_id=#{ENV['FACEBOOK_APP_ID']}&redirect_uri=#{request.url}&scope=#{User::BASIC_PERMISSIONS}"
    redirect_to "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth/?client_id=#{ENV['FACEBOOK_APP_ID']}&redirect_uri=#{request.url}&scope=#{User::BASIC_PERMISSIONS}" and return false
  end

  true
end
```

So far, all this works fine - after logging in, facebook redirects me to the right url. However, the redirect would have to happen through a post request, because otherwise the Request record won't be created. Does facebook support that? Ideally, in a way that my post parameters don't get lost along the way? I have checked [facebook's documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/oauth/) on the matter and searched the web, but couldn't find anything.